# mssql сделать уникальным поле типа xml

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, xml

Имеется MSSQL, есть ряд таблиц, где единственное поле - поле типа `xml`

На поля типа `xml` нельзя накладывать `unique` при создании, так же как и нельзя использовать индексы (по крайней мере, у меня не получилось).

Нужно сделать так, чтобы поле было уникальным.

То есть если мы внесли сначала:

```
<main>
   <param1>first</param1>
   <param2>second</param2>
</main>
```

То идентичный файл не попадет в таблицу. Но, например, вот такой попасть должен:

```
<main>
   <param1>first</param1>
   <param2>second</param2>
   <total>second</total>
</main>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Колонку типа xml действительно нельзя сделать уникальной. В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/create-xml-data-type-variables-and-columns?view=sql-server-2017#specifying-constraints) сказано:

> note that the xml data type does not support the following column and table constraints:
>   ...
>   UNIQUE
>   ...

Довольно часто предлагают добавить в таблицу дополнительную колонку (можно вычисляемую) с какой-либо информацией, извлечённой из xml (id) и уже на неё наложить ограничение.

Пример:

```
create table #t (
    a xml,
    b as convert(nvarchar(500), a),
    constraint uq_b unique(b)
)
```

Здесь в таблице колонка `a` типа `xml` и вычисляемая колонка `b`, представляющая из себя конвертированное в строку значение, на него уже можно наложить констрейнт. Однако, длина такого поля ограничена.

---

Индексы на поле типа `xml` накладывать можно. Смотрите [XML Indexes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-indexes-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Проблема в том, что нет конкретного поля, которое всегда уникально, чтобы по тему делать доп.поле

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev - если нет уникального поля, тогда только по всему содержимому делать, как предложено. Можно ещё попробовать, например, хеши сравнивать.