# MS SQL и уникальный индекс на длинные колонки

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть несколько колонок длиною 255 символов, и когда я на них вешал уникальный индекс, то мне выдало предупреждение, что я вышел за границу допустимого размера.

Это получается, что этот индекс мне не гарантирует, что в БД не могут быть добавлены дубликаты?

Comment: Гарантирует. Просто строки данных, у которых вставляемые значения в ключевых столбцах переполняют размер ключа, не будут вставлены/обновлены.

Comment: Т.е если если у меня уже вставлено ааа, и я вставлю аааб, то вставка не произойдет?

Comment: произойдет. не вставятся слишком длинные значения

Comment: @Mike, а можно ли как-то от этого уйти и дать возможность вставлять длинные значения с проверкой на уникальность?

Comment: вряд ли. я бы писал кроме строки ее md5 или другой(другие) хеш (возможно автоматом в триггере) и проверял на уникальность этот хеш. Правда есть некоторая вероятность коллизии хеша ... В любом случае поиск, даже по индексу, очень длинных строк слишком медленный. часто гораздо быстрее бывает посчитать сначала md5, а потом искать по нему

Comment: @iluxa1810, _"возможность вставлять длинные значения с проверкой на уникальность"_ в принципе можно такое закастомить (если, конечно, по-другому действительно никак). Данная задача и, например, [эта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/879723/193999) или [эта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575866/193999) решаются по сути однотипно. 1) нужна функция сравнения двух строк/сущностей (в данном случае всё просто), 2) вставляется 1 строка или несколько?, 3) делать ли поиск возможного дубликата по всей таблице или по части (используя прямые или косвенные признаки - напр. хэш), 4) есть ли concurrency